# Visualizing a clustering result with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, fuzzy-c-means

I ran a fuzzy c-means clustering algorithm on a dataset of size (11464, 2622) with 10 clusters and that yields a (10, 11464) size centers with Final fuzzy c-partitioned matrix of size (10, 2622).

My challenge is how to plot assigned clusters, for each data point in my dataset. I tried this below but didnt work.

```
cluster_membership = np.argmax(u, axis=0)
colors = ['b', 'orange', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'Brown','ForestGreen']

for j in range(10):
  x = data[:, 0]
  y = data[:, 1]
  plt.scatter(x[cluster_membership == j], y[cluster_membership == j], '.', color=colors[j])
```

where u is the partitioned matrix. but I get the error below `ufunc 'sqrt' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Can someone point me on the right direction to get my visualization? Regards

P.S I am following this example [here](http://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/auto_examples/plot_cmeans.html#example-plot-cmeans-py)

Comment: What is `u`? What is the datatype of `x` and `y`?

Comment: @DYZ u is my final partitioned matrix and datatype of x and y is int64.

Comment: Oh thanks I got the mistake @DYZ the third argument shouldn't be there.